# Big Data In TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a chat room. I found that when the data is too big, every time I enter the chat room will delay 3 to 5 seconds.

In my viewWillAppear func, I get the chat data and reloadData tableView.

Now my data.count is 49430.

Is there any solution to make this problem solve, please help me, thanks！！

Comment: What's the really taking time: Getting data ? Parsing Data? Showing data into the TableView shouldn't take long in itself.

Comment: I think is getting data. It take a while to get into chat room.

Comment: You need to clarify it yourself. Check what's really taking time. Also, what info do you retrieve? What's your logic code, or any code? Do you make multiple API calls? Only one? Is it a local data base call? Do you wait to get all messages before showing? Can you get only "last" messages first? Can you use pagination?

Comment: just go for pagination get that in chunks for example get the last 30 messages and when user scroll call api again to fetch more 30

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways would be to show the data 20 by 20 by (20 just an example the purpose here is to split the data) doing `pagination`.In order to do this, the backend service must be available.

What you need to do is to say service send next 20 data to tableview's willDisplayCell.You can do this when the user scrolls to the last cell in willDisplaycell.

Example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastElement = 20 - 2 // We call it a little before the end so that the user does not notice that the data is coming.

    if indexPath.row == lastElement{
        page = page + 1 // We tell the backend that the page has increased so it will fetch us the next 20 data

        callService() // calling service

    }
}
```